# how to mount aufs filesystem?

Tags: aufs

I've been learning docker and decided to try out the unionfs `aufs`. But I couldn't find a way to do it.

I tried `mount -t aufs` but it complained that aufs was unknown.

```
$ sudo mount -t aufs -o dirs=./container-layer:./image-layer4:./image-layer3:./image-layer2:./image-layer1 none ./mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'aufs'
```

I've searched the Internet but still can't figure out a way to mount aufs filesystem. I'd appriciate it if someone can tell how to mount aufs filesystem or just redirect me to some links.

**OS**: Ubuntu16.04

**uname -a**:

```
Linux myzone 4.14.13-041413-generic #201801101001 SMP Wed Jan 10 10:02:53 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

By the way, no **aufs** in `/proc/filesystem` and `aufs-tools` was installed.

Comment: Use overlayfs, it provides the same functionality

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, you need to rebuild your kernel so it includes aufs either as a builtin filesystem or as a module.

Answer (score 0):

Current best practice is to use OverlayFS instead of AUFS. Ideally overlay2 rather than overlay.

> OverlayFS is a modern union filesystem that is similar to AUFS, but faster and with a simpler implementation.

See https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ for details.